# How to tell what part of a THREE.Geometry object (vertices and faces) are viewable in the camera frustum?

Tags: three.js, geometry

I'm trying to dynamically add and remove children (text labels) to a scene depending on what parts of a geometry object I can see. I have too many vertices to label (4 million) that I cannot add them all to the scene at once, hence only adding the number visible on the screen. Can somebody recommend an approach to take to achieve this?

NB. I have a large 2D plane with points across the x & y axes which I can pan and zoom in and out of. I'm trying to add 2D labels (canvas-to-texture) to those points once I've reached a certain zoom value. A glorified webgl scatterplot basically!

Comment: Sounds like you want https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/objects/LOD.js

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately using the LOD class would suddenly add 1 million text labels once I've reached a certain zoom level (if it was applied to the geometry object). If I applied the LOD class to every single point, then once I reached a certain distance away from the points, only those points would then display their text labels. Either way sounds expensive. I guess I'm trying to an intersection of the camera frustrum and the geometry object...?

Comment: In fact, it sounds almost exactly what I'm after, will try to see if there are any examples out there using Frustum (just realised it's not frustrum) - http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Frustum